# Problem with nividia drivers

Tags: nvidia

I am running Ubuntu 12.04 on a hp  workstation Z820 (with NVIDIA NVS 510 2GB graphic card), I use a display port for the screen. The system works fine generally but if the screen is off for a while and I want to turn it on, then it goes black / gets disturbed some times.

I also tried a DVI-D cable with a mini port adapter then resolution is too low.

I guess some thing is wrong with Graphic card drivers but do not know how to fix it. Could any one help me with this issue? I appreciate a lot!

/Omid

Comment: Did you install the nVidia graphics or you use the one supplied by Ubuntu?

Comment: It is installed by the factory then it should be the NVIDIA graphic card

Answer (score 0):

[this link should help you, works for me](http://www.noobslab.com/2012/10/install-latest-nvidia-drivers-in-ubuntu.html)

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: Thank you so much, the link is very useful and it works for me as well but I tried the following flow which is suggested in one of the comments on the web page:                                                   
1) sudo apt-get install linux-source
2) sudo apt-get install linux
3) sudo apt-get autoremove nvidia-current
4) sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg xserver-xorg-video-all
5) sudo apt-add-repository ppa:noobslab/nvidia-quantal
6) sudo apt-get update
7) sudo apt-get install nvidia-current
8) sudo reboot

Answer (score 0):

Ok since you said you are on the default drivers mayby it should be best to install the nvidia ones:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-x-swat/x-updates
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nvidia-current
```

This may fix the problem. If not, let me know and I will try and edit my answer

Comment: Yes those three comments suppose to solve the problem but I had to run some more comments as well and now it is fixed. Thanks for your answers. Here are those comments I used:

Comment: 1) sudo apt-get install linux-source 2) sudo apt-get install linux 3) sudo apt-get autoremove nvidia-current 4) sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg xserver-xorg-video-all 5) sudo apt-add-repository ppa:noobslab/nvidia-quantal 6) sudo apt-get update 7) sudo apt-get install nvidia-current 8) sudo reboot